# Windows 7: Lines through menu items

Tags: windows-7

I recently reinstalled my PC only to find this very strange problem persists.

The only way for me to describe this is to show you:

[image]

It seems to randomly appear in any application, I'm using an ATI graphics card. Does anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: When this problem occurs, download the free version of SIW from http://www.gtopala.com/ and run it.  If you download the installable, you don't need the registry viewer. Find the Video option under Hardware, and take a screenshot of that page.  Make sure to catch the "Core Temperature" if it's listed.  Also make sure to catch "Video Processor" and expand the "Performance Level" marked "Current" if it's listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure the video drivers are up to date 
run memtest86 (it could be system ram)
Second since it seems to be related to video card , make sure its seated well
Third try a replacement card
Fourth try same app in safe mode

How long ago did it start?

Comment: I can recall it being around for the last 2 weeks or so. I've just done a clean install today, only suspect thing I've run is a portable version of PS.